# How i can find hostname in wifi lan using jmDNS?

Tags: java, android, wifi, hostname, jmdns

I working with IoT (Arduino and ESP32).
I am able to assign a hostname to the board using mDNS.
I want from an Android App to write the url "arduino.local" and get the IP address (for example 198.162.1.25".
I have tried with jmDNS and I don't know how to list the services found.

Library: implementation 'org.jmdns:jmdns:3.5.7'

This is my code:

```java
package com.anaconet.jmdns;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Context;

// jmDNS .........................................
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.util.Log;

import javax.jmdns.JmDNS;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceListener;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceEvent;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceInfo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "jmDNS (PAUL)... ";
    private static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.local.";
    //private static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_workstation._tcp.local.";

    private String type = "_dynamix._tcp.local.";
    private static JmDNS jmdns = null;
    private ServiceListener listener = null;
    private ServiceInfo serviceInfo;

    private static MulticastLock multicastLock;
    boolean isDiscovering;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        isDiscovering = false;
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        multicastLock = wifi.createMulticastLock("jmdns-multicast-lock");
        multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
    }

    private InetAddress getDeviceIpAddress(WifiManager wifi) {
        InetAddress result = null;
        try {
            // default to Android localhost
            result = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");

            // figure out our wifi address, otherwise bail
            WifiInfo wifiinfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
            int intaddr = wifiinfo.getIpAddress();
            byte[] byteaddr = new byte[] { (byte) (intaddr & 0xff), (byte) (intaddr >> 8 & 0xff),
                    (byte) (intaddr >> 16 & 0xff), (byte) (intaddr >> 24 & 0xff) };
            result = InetAddress.getByAddress(byteaddr);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, String.format("getDeviceIpAddress Error: %s", ex.getMessage()));
        }

        return result;
    }


    private class ServiceListenerImpl implements ServiceListener {
        @Override
        public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
            event.getDNS().requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName());
            System.out.println("Service added: " + event.getInfo());
        }

        @Override
        public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent event) {
            //Handle service dropping out.
            System.out.println("Service removed: " + event.getInfo());
        }

        @Override
        public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Service resolved: " + event.getInfo());
            System.out.println("Service resolved: "
                    + event.getInfo().getQualifiedName()
                    + " port:" + event.getInfo().getPort());
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart()  {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting ServiceActivity...");
        super.onStart();
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting Mutlicast Lock...");
            WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            // get the device ip address
            final InetAddress deviceIpAddress = getDeviceIpAddress(wifi);
            multicastLock = wifi.createMulticastLock(getClass().getName());
            multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
            multicastLock.acquire();
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting ZeroConf probe....");
            // Create a JmDNS instance
            // JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(address, "JmDNS-IP-" + (jmdnsInstances.size() + 1));
            jmdns = JmDNS.create(deviceIpAddress, "HOSTNAME");
            if (jmdns != null) {
                // Add a service listener
                jmdns.addServiceListener(SERVICE_TYPE, new ServiceListenerImpl());
//                jmdns.list("_exp._tcp.local.", 10 * 1000);
                isDiscovering = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "discovering services of type: "  + SERVICE_TYPE);

/*
                serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_test._tcp.local.",
                        "AndroidTest", 0,
                        "test from android");
                jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);

 */
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Started ZeroConf probe....");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Stopping ServiceActivity...");
        super.onStop();
        stopScan();
    }

    private static void stopScan() {
        try {
            if (jmdns != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Stopping ZeroConf probe....");
                jmdns.unregisterAllServices();
                jmdns.close();
                jmdns = null;
            }
            if (multicastLock != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Releasing Mutlicast Lock...");
                multicastLock.release();
                multicastLock = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

List all IP and Hostname connected to WiFi.